# Can't get modified value from textbox in gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to get `gridview` data using `jquery`. I have modified existing data on `textbox` and try to get that value using `jquery`. but it gave old value in `textbox`. not modified value in `textbox`.

**ASPX Code**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

    /*javascripts and stylesheets are here*/

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Navigate() {
            $('#dialogDiv').dialog('open');
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var list = "";
            $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: true,
                width: 300,
                height: 'auto',
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $("#<%=Type_GV.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
                            //Skip first(header) row
                            if (!this.rowIndex) return;
                            var type = $(this).find("td:last").html();
                            list += type + "</br>";
                        });
                        alert(list)
                    }
                }
            });
        }); 

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="dialogDiv" title="Type" style="overflow: hidden">
        <div id="TypeDiv" class="divTable">
            <div class="divRow">
                <div class="divColumn">
                    <div>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="open" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="Type_GV" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Type") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="open" runat="server" Text="Open dialog" OnClientClick="Navigate()"
        OnClick="open_Clicked" />
    <br />
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveType" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveType_Clicked" Style="visibility: hidden;
            display: none;" />
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void open_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
            VehicleType vTypeObject = new VehicleType();
            Type_GV.DataSource = vTypeObject.GetTypeList();
            Type_GV.DataBind();
    }


    protected void btnSaveType_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in Type_GV.Rows)
        {
            TextBox type = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtType");
            Debug.WriteLine("type : " + type.Text);                
        }
    }


public class VehicleType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<VehicleType> GetTypeList()
    {
        List<VehicleType> list = new List<VehicleType>()
    {
        new VehicleType{Type="Type1"},
        new VehicleType{Type="Type2"}
    };
        return list;
    }
}
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Are you getting alert at the save click?

Comment: @DKM yes.I'm getting alert at the save click with the old value on `textbox`. not the new/modified value.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

*As you are using the update panels, `this.remove_endRequest()` is raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.*

Not sure but i think this the issue, i faced these kind of issues many times. Might be helpful to you.

[See Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest($(function(){
      var list = "";
        $('#dialogDiv').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            width: 300,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $("#<%=Type_GV.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
                        //Skip first(header) row
                        if (!this.rowIndex) return;
                        var type = $(this).find("td:last").html();
                        list += type + "</br>";
                    });
                    alert(list)
                }
            }
        });
});)
```

**Note:** Don't remove `$(document).ready(function{}))` keep it as it is, and include this one.

Comment: I have added like this. `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest($(document).ready(function () { /* Code Here*/ }));`. but console in `chrome` reported error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined`. `Sys` is from here `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager`

Comment: @Bishan Set `EnablePartialRendering="true"` to your script manager tag.

Comment: still getting same error after adding like `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>`

Comment: Now only one option remaining put your `<script>` tag in `<body>`, Aren't you using master page? or is this the master page?

Comment: I have master page. but it is not this one.

Comment: where should i place this on my master page ?

Comment: you can see there is a method called `btnSaveType_Clicked` in my partial class. i'm tried to get `gridview` textbox value using that method as well as using jquery. you can see there is a `Debug` line. when i debug programe, it also gave me old value. not the new value. if we forgot getting data using jquery and tried get data using partial class, what should i do for get modified data from partial class ? can i use `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest()` in partial class instead of in `<script>` tag ? or any other way to get modified data from partial class ?

Comment: Why don't you put your script manager only once in master page in `<body>`

Comment: sorry. i'm new to .NET development. so still studying things on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34062/discussion-between-dkm-and-bishan)